# How to install libgfortran.so.4 from source

Tags: amazon-ec2, installation

ImportError: libgfortran.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I am getting this error .
Here the requirement is  I need to install libgfortran.so.4 from souse ?
could any one help me on that.

Thanks.

I need to install libgfortran.so.4 from souse .